# WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0: setting hostname

Tags: certificate, wso2, hostname, wso2-es

In **WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0** there is a mix about the hostname used to make connections.

You can set **HostName** and **MgtHostName** in **carbon.xml**. But there are files with *fixed* names, like

- **sso-idp-config.xml**: (AssertionConsumerService) https://**localhost**:9443/store/acs
- jaggeryapps\store\controllers\ **login.jag**: (postUrl) "https://" + process.getProperty('**carbon.local.ip**') + ":" ...

**localhost** breaks every remote connection. **IP address** breaks SAML authentication and is not consistent with 3rd party certificates.

Is there an easy way to set the hostname all over the ES?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this scenario only by updating AssertionConsumerService within sso-idp-config.xml and it works for me.

So you have to only update AssertionConsumerService within sso-idp-config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

To work properly, the full list of files I had to modify is:

- repository\conf\sso-idp-config.xml
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\controllers\login.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\controllers\logout.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\social\controllers\login.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\social\controllers\logout.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\controllers\login.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\controllers\logout.jag
- repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\themes\store\js\asset.js

login/logout files use the IP address (a bad choice when working with third-party certificates. It also breaks SAML authentication).

I lost a lot of time locating files with IP and localhost references. I think it should be reviewed and documented in future versions of the product.